# Evitar que uma action seja interceptada pelo Interceptor Handle

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Implementei uma classe para interceptar algumas urls e verificar se tenho um usuario logado na sessão, se sim acesso a url, caso contrário sou automaticamente "jogado" para a tela de login.

Acontece que na pagina de um login eu tenho um link para cadastrar um usuário no meu sistema, só que como não tenho um usuário na sessão pois sou um usuário que ainda vou me cadastrar, gostaria de saber como liberar minha action `adicionaUsuario` do interceptor e deixar com que eu efetue o cadastro do usuário. Hoje ao cadastrar um usuário sou levado novamente para a tela de login.

Debugando, quando clico no botão que chama a action `adicionaUsuario` ele nem chega até o método, ele retorna `true` no interceptor e já me leva para a página de login.

Segue abaixo o meu método `preHandle` do meu interceptor e o meu método para adicionar usuário que vem do controller:

```
public class AutorizadorInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object controller) throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if( uri.endsWith("loginForm") || uri.endsWith("efetuaLogin") || uri.contains("resources") || uri.endsWith("mainUsuario") || uri.endsWith("adicionaUsuario") ) {
            return true;
        }

        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null) {
            return true;
        }
        response.sendRedirect("loginForm");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "adicionaUsuario")
    public String adicionaUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        usuarioService.adicionaUsuario(usuario);


        return  "usuarioSuccess";
    }
```

Comment: mas se você retorna "true" não está dizendo que DEVE interceptar o evento?

Comment: Algum motivo para não usar o Spring Security?

Comment: Que tal no método `adicionaUsuario` colocar o usuário na sessão?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi o adicionaUsuario já recebe o objeto preenchido do form com os dados do novo usuário. Até ai está ok!
seu erro está na sintaxe, aparentemente a confirmação da tela está correta, vc está dando um true na página aberta. Porém vc está direcionando o usuário para a página usuariosuccess que não tem permissão de acesso. Tente permitir o acesso dele para esse direcionamento e se o erro persistir veja se o método adicionaUsuario é acessível por todos.

Answer (score -1):

olha, acho que seu problema está exatamente na forma como escreveu o método preHandle()

repare ao debugar que caso a primeira condição seja satisfeita você já encerra o método dando return true;

ou seja não será executado as linhas de código abaixo pois o método já retornou a resposta na primeira condição IF...

Answer (score -1):

Ao inves de utilizar `request.getRequestURI()`use `request.getServletPath()`